# Toggle Expandable background on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to create a link; eg. 'Click here for background demo'. And then by clicking the link; the background of the webpage would then display an image, and that image is expandable.

I have an expandable background solution at stand alone; using the below.

But how could I have only display 'on click'; to become implemented.

```
<!--Expandable BG code IE 7 +-->

  <style>

                #bg { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; }
                .bgwidth { width: 100%; }
                .bgheight { height: 100%; }

                #page-wrap { position: relative; width: 950px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;;  }

  </style> 


 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
                $(function() {   
                        var theWindow        = $(window),
                            $bg              = $("#bg"),
                            aspectRatio      = $bg.width() / $bg.height();

                        function resizeBg() {

                                if ( (theWindow.width() / theWindow.height()) < aspectRatio ) {
                                    $bg
                                        .removeClass()
                                        .addClass('bgheight');
                                } else {
                                    $bg
                                        .removeClass()
                                        .addClass('bgwidth');
                                }

                        }

                        theWindow.resize(function() {
                                resizeBg();
                        }).trigger("resize");

                });
        </script>


<!--Expandable BG code IE 7 +-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have following `resize` handler

```
theWindow.resize(function() {
    resizeBg();
}).trigger("resize");
```

If you want to invoke it on clicking on a link then you can use

```
$('a.link').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    resizeBg();
});
```

Just put the code given for `click` after/before your `theWindow.resiz` handler. Also make sure that you have an `a` tag with class `link`, like

```
<a href="#" class="link">Click</a>
```

And remove `.trigger("resize");` from the `resize` handler to stop the handler being invoked onload.